# swift - delete or replace <null> values from nested dictionary

Tags: swift, swifty-json, codable

I have some data from server, and I'm using `Alamofire SwiftyJSON` to convert it to `[String: Any]`. Then I'm saving it to plist using `SwiftyPlistManager`. The point is that `SwiftyPlistManager` crashed when saving `<null>`, so I need to replace all `<null>`or `nil`to `""`.

My Dictionary after `Alamofire SwiftyJSON` looks this way:

```
["info_editable": true,
 "name": Android Q,
 "is_message": true,
 "images": [["id": 92,
             "image": /media/product/102.png]],
 "video_description": <null>,
 "is_valid": true]
```

or it could be -

```
["info_editable": true,
 "name": Android Q,
 "is_message": true,
 "images": <null>,
 "video_description": <null>,
 "is_valid": true]
```

I suppose to use `Codable` from raw data, but have no idea how to set initial value as empty string or `[[]]`, then check if parced data is `<null>` and leave initial value as default.
Or is there any way to list nested dictionary to replace `<null>`to `""`?

Comment: var updatedDictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: yourDictionary.map { ($0, $1 != nil ? $1! : "") })

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var dic = ["1":nil,"2":"33","3":"5444"]
let res = dic.mapValues { $0 == nil ? "" : $0 }
print(res) // ["1": Optional(""), "2": Optional("33"), "3": Optional("5444")]
```

Answer (score 0):

for now, my best idea is -

1) stringify every value except array of dictionaries,

2) check if string content "null", then replace it with `""`if true.

3) array of dictionaries, if stringified, will have 2 option - with `[[` and `]]`(then checking every dictionary like above) or without - in case of `"images": <null>,`(so `<null>` should be replaced with`[[]]`.
but I have about 7 requests with different data, should be parsed this strange way, and I hope to found more pretty decision.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a protocolish solution, that goes recursively through dictionaries and arrays:

```swift
/// Allows clients to ask the receiver to remove any `NSNull` instances
protocol NullStripable {
    func strippingNulls() -> Self
}

extension Array: NullStripable {
    func strippingNulls() -> Self {
        return compactMap {
            switch $0 {
            case let strippable as NullStripable:
                // the forced cast here is necessary as the compiler sees
                // `strippable` as NullStripable, as we casted it from `Element`
                return (strippable.strippingNulls() as! Element)
            case is NSNull:
                return nil
            default:
                return $0
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Dictionary: NullStripable {
    func strippingNulls() -> Self {
        return compactMapValues {
            switch $0 {
            case let strippable as NullStripable:
                // the forced cast here is necessary as the compiler sees
                // `strippable` as NullStripable, as we casted it from `Value`
                return (strippable.strippingNulls() as! Value)
            case is NSNull:
                return nil
            default:
                return $0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```swift
let dict: [String: Any] = [
    "items": ["info_editable": true,
              "name": "Android Q",
              "is_message": true,
              "images": [["id": 92,
                          "image": "/media/product/102.png"]],
              "video_description": NSNull(),
              "is_valid": true],
    "somethingElse": NSNull()
]

print(dict.strippingNulls())
```

Sample output:

```
["items": ["name": "Android Q", "info_editable": true, "images": [["image": "/media/product/102.png", "id": 92]], "is_message": true, "is_valid": true]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. It will remove null and replace with blank string, without loosing key.

```
func removeNullFromResponse(response:NSDictionary) -> NSDictionary{
    
    let blankString = "\"\""
    let myMutableDict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: response)

    var data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:myMutableDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

    var strData = NSString.init(data: data!, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    strData = strData?.replacingOccurrences(of: "<NULL>", with: blankString) as NSString?
    strData = strData?.replacingOccurrences(of: "<null>", with: blankString) as NSString?
    strData = strData?.replacingOccurrences(of: "<Null>", with: blankString) as NSString?
    strData = strData?.replacingOccurrences(of: "NULL", with: blankString) as NSString?
    strData = strData?.replacingOccurrences(of: "null", with: blankString) as NSString?
    
    data = strData?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
    
    var dictionary = NSDictionary()
    
    do
    {
        dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! , options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! NSDictionary
        
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
    return dictionary as NSDictionary
}
```

Comment: This is a very impractical solution. What if any value contains the replacement object, e.g. Vanilla contains nil, the value will get replaced with blank string and will return error.